# Как сделать смену темы на сайте?

Tags: html, css

Делаю сайт. Хочу чтобы на нём можно было изменять тему нажатием ссылки (да, именно ссылки, так как такой стиль). Например: на сайте есть ссылка с надписью: "change theme", и при нажатии на неё тема меняется. Поскольку сайт выполнен полностью в чёрно-белых тонах, то очень желательно было бы сделать всё через параметр `invert()` в css.

Comment: При нажатии ссылки добавь класс к телу сайта. `invert()` не поменяет тему, его предназначение совершенно другое.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если коротко, то суть такая: в обертке сайта (тег body или div) создается дополнительный класс, указывающий на выбранную тему и далее, исходя из этого класса прописываются стили.
А чтобы выбранная пользователем тема никуда не сбрасывалась, ни при обновлении страницы, ни при выходе из браузера, данные о выборе записываются в local storage. Вот пример:

```js
const themeToggle = document.getElementById('theme-toggle')
    const app = document.getElementById('app')
    //проверяем последнюю выбранную пользователем тему
    function chosenTheme() {
      if(localStorage.getItem('theme') === 'dark') {
        app.classList.add('dark');
      }
      if(localStorage.getItem('theme') === 'light') {
        app.classList.add('light');
      }
    }
    //переключаем тему по клику на ссылку
    const themeChange = () => {
      if(app.classList.contains('light')) {
        app.classList.remove('light');
        app.classList.add('dark');
        localStorage.removeItem('theme', 'light')
        localStorage.setItem('theme', 'dark')
      } else {
        app.classList.remove('dark');
        app.classList.add('light');
        localStorage.removeItem('theme', 'dark')
        localStorage.setItem('theme', 'light')
      }
    }
    themeToggle.addEventListener('click', themeChange)
    chosenTheme()
```

```css
.light h1 {
      color: red;
    }

    .dark h1 {
      color: blue;
    }
```

```html
<div id="app" class="light">
  <h1>Title</h1> 
  <a id="theme-toggle" class="">change theme</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

ну один из способов (не знаю насколько он эффективен и уместен)

1. добавляем в `body` класс `my-style-1`

   ```
    <body class = 'my-style-1'>
   ```
2. при нажатии на ссылке меняем  класс на другой

   ```
    document.querySelector('body').classList.toggle("my-style-1");
    document.querySelector('body').classList.toggle("my-style-2");
   ```

(ну или любым другим прямым способом)

3. все стили для разных тем прописываем в виде

   ```
    .my-style-1 классы и т.д. {
    }

    .my-style-2 классы и т.д. {
    }
   ```

а на счет

> нажатием ссылки (да, именно ссылки, так как такой стиль).

то какая разница на что нажимать?

а ссылка это вообще обычный `div` с подчеркиванием текста и дополнительным стилем `:hover`

Comment: Не совсем понял как прописать стили для классов. У меня в проекте есть другие классы, поэтому класс в классе выдаёт ошибку.

Comment: ну придется переделывать и надо как-то подгружать css стили динамически (т.е. файлы) - поищите тогда в этом направлении